# Reading upto newline

Tags: c, file-io

Hi
My program reads a CSV file.
So I used fgets to read one line at a time.
But now the interface specification says that it is possible to find NULL characters in few of the columns.
So I need to replace fgets with another function to read from the file
Any suggestions?

Comment: Because fgets reads only a string so if a nul character is present in a line then it will read only till nul and not end of line.

Comment: That is wrong. `fgets` always reads to newline or EOF. However, it takes a bit of work to deal with embedded newlines using `fgets`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fgets` works perfectly well with embedded null bytes. Pre-fill your buffer with `\n` (using `memset`) and then use `memchr(buf, '\n', sizeof buf)`. If `memchr` returns `NULL`, your buffer was too small and you need to enlarge it to read the rest of the line. Otherwise, you can determine whether the newline you found is the end of the line or the padding you pre-filled the buffer with by inspecting the next byte. If the newline you found is at the end of the buffer or has another newline just after it, it's from padding, and the previous byte is the null terminator inserted by `fgets` (not a null from the file). Otherwise, the newline you found has a null byte after it (terminator inserted by `fgets`, and it's the end-of-line newline.

Other approaches will be slow (repeated `fgetc`) or waste (and risk running out of) resources (loading the whole file into memory).

Comment: @R .. I realized that my issue is not with fgets but with the string functions I am using after that.thanks a lot T3

Answer (score 3):

If your text stream has a `NUL` (ascii 0) character, you will need to handle your file as a binary file and use `fread` to read the file. There are two approaches to this.

1. Read the entire file into memory. The length of the file can be obtained by `fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END)` and then calling `ftell`.You can then allocate enough memory for the whole file.Once in memory, parsing the file should be relatively easy. This approach is only really suitable for smallish files (probably less than 50M max). For bonus marks look at the `mmap` function.
2. Read the file byte by byte and add the characters to a buffer until a newline is found.
3. Read and parse bit by bit. Create a buffer that is biggest than you largest line and fill it with content from your file. You then parse and extract as many lines as you can. Add the remainder to the beginning of a new buffer an read the next bit. Using a bigger buffer will help minimize copying.

Comment: Thanks will try the first option.

Answer (score 1):

use fread and then scan the block for the separator

Check the function `int T_fread(FILE *input)` at http://www.mrx.net/c/source.html

Comment: but I dont know the max size of each line . How do I decide the length . Also how will I reset the file pointer to the correct point.

Comment: here are the steps  (i)  Open the file (ii) get the size of the file say it is n bytes (iii) allocate a buffer say m bytes (m .LE. n) (iv) position to the begin of the start of the opened file (iv) do fread (m bytes of the file into the buffer) until the whole file is read (v) walk through the buffer to detect the separator and the NULL.   As an optimization I would suggest you consider replacing the NULL with another character such as space or newline or an appropriate character - then you can continue using the standard string library functions